# relationship between BMO norm and $L_p$ norm

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Are there any relationship between the BMO norm of a function and its $L_p$ norms? For example, one norm is controlled by the other for functions of some special class.

Comment: what is BMO norm ?

Comment: BMO is short for "bounded mean oscillation". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BMO is a bit like the space $L_\infty$, and also a bit like the Orlicz norm corresponding to $e^x$.  So if you are on a bounded domain, then BMO is a subspace of $L_p$ for every $1 \le p < \infty$, with $\|f\|_p \le c_p \|f\|_{\text{BMO}}$ where $c_p$ grows like $p$.  However $L_\infty$ is a subspace of BMO, and there are functions in BMO that are not in $L_\infty$, for example, $-\log |x|$ on $[-1,1]$.

Also BMO has the following property: there exist functions $0 \le g \le f$ such that $f \in \text{BMO}$, but $g \notin \text{BMO}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems that BMO is a lattice. We can prove that $\||f|\|_{BMO}\le 2\|f\|_{BMO}$ and $\max\{f,g\}$ can be written in terms of absolute value.

Comment: Oops - maybe I meant to say that if $0 \le g \le f$, and $f \in \text{BMO}$, this doesn't necessarily mean $g \in \text{BMO}$.

Comment: Interesting point. I can see intuitively that a non BMO function $g$ can be under a "flat" roof $f$, but I cannot give an example.

Comment: If I remember correctly - try $f(x) = \log |x|$ on $[-1,1]$, and $g(x) = (\log x) I_{x>0}$.

Comment: Great. I will take $f(x)=|log|x||$ and $g(x)=f(x)I_{x>0}$. Then $f\ge g\ge 0$ and $f$ is in BMO($\mathbb{R}$) but g is not. Could you please edit your first answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: It is not true that the L^p norm of f is less than c_p times the BMO norm of f.  Something very similar to this is true, but recall that f+C has the same BMO norm as f for any constant C.  Adding constants allows you to increase the L^p norm arbitrarily without affecting the BMO norm.

Comment: @LoganStokols Yes, I think you are correct, although sometimes the BMO norm is defined as adding the $L^\infty$ norm to it to get around this issue.